# Display data other than data that is selected in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How to display data other than data that is selected in MySQL.

[image]

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: There are too many tags with no associated code.

Comment: That would be quite clever @ArtisticPhoenix - Even more with what they've been given so far, and along with the proverbial *"It doesn't work"*, heh.

Comment: It's actually a very simple query, a MySQL 101 level query.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: select * from table a join table b on a.col_a = b.col_a where b.status != 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select from the first table, as in:

```
select col_a
  from table1 
  where col_a not in (
    select col_a from table2 where status = 1
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple negate statement:

```
SELECT COL_A
FROM Table
WHERE Status <> 1
```

This selects names from `COL_A` where Status does not equal 1.

Comment: I imagine you have to replace `Table` with your actual table name...  You could try this `SELECT COL_A
FROM Table
WHERE Status != 1`

Comment: Where is Pisang in? Do you have another table? How is that table associated with the first table?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `<>` and `!=` are functionally identical in MySQL

Comment: Yes, I know they are.  As for "Pisang" if its in another table, you'll have to do a LEFT JOIN probably if it doesn't exist in the other table, but without more information were just guessing.